# Append element to body tag of page only, not to iframe facebook, google+, twister

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append

In website which embeds iframes of facebook and google+, When I try to append a div tag to the body of page, it also appends to the iframe. How could I just only append to body tag of page ?

```
var divSpeed = document.createElement("div");   
divSpeed.innerHTML = "..."
$(document.body).append(divSpeed);
```

I'm writing a chrome extension, and in contentscript, i can't set id for body tag of page. So please help me a way which not set id for body tag.

Comment: Fiddle please? This should not happen, especially because of CORS.

Comment: whether the script is in the iframe or the main page

Comment: The script is in the main page

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the body like

```
<body id = "main_body">
```

and use

```
$('#main_body').append(divSpeed);
```

It has worked for me in a project.